# Getting a new array from another array based on matching value

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-map, array-filter

I have an array of thousands objects and need to check if a specific value is included in one of the values.

My array:

```
const images = [
  {
    "name" : "sky",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["pink", "yellow", "red"],
  },
  {
    "name" : "old car",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["dark purple", "sand", "light green"],
  },
  {
    "name" : "sky",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["dark blue", "violet"],
  },
...
]
```

and I'm trying to get a new array that contains only those objects which include a specific colour. Also the value must be a perfect match: i.e. if I pass "blue" it should return false if it checks against "dark blue"

I'm trying to do the following but running into errors

```
const checkColourtHandler = async (selectedColour) => {
   const imageList = images.filter(function (item, i) {
        if (item.colours.includes(selectedColour)) {
          return true;
        } else return false;
   });
   console.log(imageList);
}
```

Ideally I'm looking for the best performant method as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `filter` and `includes` methods to check for matching elements:

```js
const images = [
  {
    "name" : "sky",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["pink", "yellow", "red"],
  },
  {
    "name" : "old car",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["dark purple", "sand", "light green"],
  },
  {
    "name" : "sky",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["dark blue", "violet"],
  }
];

const filtered = (col) => images.filter(i => i.colours.includes(col));

const output = filtered('dark blue');

console.log(output);
console.log(filtered('blue'));
```

Comment: Thanks @DigitalDrifter it looks like it is working however it returns a function. In reality I'm trying to get the array as final result so I can save it and use it elsewhere.

Comment: Where is it returning a function? I'm just defining `filtered` as a function and calling it with desired color string: `filtered('dark blue');`. That can change to suit your implementation needs, of course.

Comment: Well I need to get and save the array result of that function somewhere. So the way I see it is that there are 2 steps: run the function and save the result in other variable so I can access it and use it elsewhere.

Comment: I updated the answer. You'll see `const output = filtered('dark blue');` now so you can reference the `output` array later in your code.

Comment: That is not working for me for some reason. I have const output = filtered('dark blue'); within another function and filtered() separate and I'm getting Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i.colours.includes'

Comment: Remove the `async` keyword from `const checkColourtHandler = async (selectedColour)`, you're not returning a promise or doing any asynchronous work, so it's unnecessary.

Comment: async removed, still getting exactly the same error

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd be getting that error. Can you update your question with your latest code?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```js
const images = [
  {
    "name" : "sky",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["pink", "yellow", "red"],
  },
  {
    "name" : "old car",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["dark purple", "sand", "light green"],
  },
  {
    "name" : "sky",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["dark blue", "violet"],
  }
];

const checkColourtHandler = (selectedColour) => images.filter(item => item.colours.includes(selectedColour));

console.log(checkColourtHandler("sand"));
console.log(checkColourtHandler("violet"));
```

Answer (score 0):

@DigitalDrifter

Updating my code here

```js
const images = [
  {
    "name" : "sky",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["pink", "yellow", "red"],
  },
  {
    "name" : "old car",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["dark purple", "sand", "light green"],
  },
  {
    "name" : "sky",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["dark blue", "violet"],
  }
];

const filtered = (col) => images.filter(i => i.colours.includes(col));

const checkColourtHandler = (selectedColour) => {
    const result = filtered(selectedColour); 
    console.log("result: ",result);
  }

checkColourtHandler('pink');
```

Comment: Find the problem, another error in my code was causing a conflict. Many thanks for your help!